# Send hidden variable when clicking hyperlink, secure sql

Tags: php, mysql

I wanted to pass a hidden variable at first with $_POST but i have come to realize that users can change $_POST almost as easily as $_GET. Is it possible to somehow restrict this ability or is there another way to do this? Also, it doesnt seem you can use $_POST in this simple example below?:

index.php

```
    <a href="test.php?variable=<?php echo $row['recipe_id'];?>"><view recipe</a>
```

test.php

```
    $variable = $_GET['variable'];
    $query = $database->query("SELECT name, description, date_added from recipe where recipe_id = $variable");
```

(EDIT: i do check that the input is indeed an integer although i skipped this above to minimize the code of the example. I should've made this clear earlier).
I guess the only borderline "malicious" things a user could do here is loop through the recipe_id:s to find out how many recipes were in the database or even the first recipe added just by changing the $variable. Not that i care in this particular case, but im sure i will when it comes to other examples. I realize that i want to make the information available, i just want it to go through the "proper channels" i guess. Is this just the way things are or am i missing something vital?

People always write things like "validate your input". And i agree with that. But in this case its just one integer the user "inputs". What can be done besides that validation? Again, im slowly progressing/learning this so please be patient if i seem to make simple mistakes.

(Using PHP, PDO, Mysql)
Thank you!

Comment: You're nieve and you should trust people when they say 'validate your input' regardless of if *you* think it's worth your time. In this case, I could modify `variable` to be: `1; DROP TABLE \`recipe\``. I guess you don't mind that?

Comment: I don't particulary trust input and i agree it should be validated. And i do check for that kind of thing, although not in this most basic example. Im just looking for more info.

Comment: Then why did you write that the worst thing that could happen is that people could iterate through all your id's to find out the number of rows? That's not the worst thing that'll happy, all your data will be stolen/deleted, which you seem blissfully unaware of. I'm just saying, be careful with data, regardless of how 'borderline malicious' you think it is.

Comment: You should never just join user input into a SQL command. Remember [Little Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/). Even if it's something noddy, try to get into the habit of doing it right - it's just as quick and easy and means you'll be a better developer for it. For the record, validating and escaping user input is also insufficient

Comment: Yes, sound advice. This is kind of why i chose this simple example. What should i do besides validate that it is indeed an integer. What can be done additionally? I tend to lurk and read alot on "how to do things" but this is the first time im actually trying to accomplish anything. So its bound to be a learning experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all about [**HTTP requests**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Http). The browser communicates with the server through HTTP requests. These are *entirely transparent* to the user however you look at it. Open the *Web Inspector* in your browser (or Firebug, or Fiddler or whatever else) and inspect the raw HTTP requests, live. Anyone can send these requests to your server anytime, containing any data at all.

Understand this concept, it is important. There's no such thing as "secret" information in the communication between your server and the client (from the POV of the client). **You do not control the input to your server.** Neither can you "hide" any data that is going from the client to your server.

An HTTP request represents a, well, *request* for data or for some action. The server should, well, *serve* the request to the best of its abilities. If a request is invalid, the server must reject it. The server should judge the validity of each request independently of every other request, it should be stateless. The server cannot presume the validity of any request without validating it. It should only ever output information which is not security sensitive and treat all incoming data as suspicious. That's the fact of life.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want users to see an incremental recipe ID that they can easily modify, then generate a unique random string to use to identify recipes. This will stop users from being able to play with the recipe ID in the GET or POST data.

They can still modify it but they will need to obtain the random string in order to pull out a recipe.

Comment: Thank you. This is a good simple thing i could do to obfuscate the pattern a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

The "variable" isn't restricted to be an integer at all in your code. An evil user could probably change the value of "variable" to "';truncate recipe;--". Execute this and whoops ... all recipes are gone.

always ensure that you use proper validation. search the interwebs for "sql injection" and have a look at functions like [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) (and it's documentation).

Comment: I agree, definately. I also should've been more clear with my question. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

The content of request fields, whether `$_POST` or `$_GET`, is not typed. It is just plain strings, which means that it's pretty much "open game" on the client side. It's the very reason we keep repeating that **client input cannot be trusted**, and must be validated on the server side.

Regarding your second question: recall that `$_GET` will contain the result of a form using the **get** `method`, while `$_POST` will contain data from **post** `method` forms. `$_GET` purpose is to contain url parameters, if they exist (to be precise, a *get* `method` form will pass all its parameters via the url).

On a side note, I should also tell you that you shouldn't use one verb for another, each one as a specific purpose. The *get* `method` is about getting data, not updating it, while *post*, *put*, *delete* are about updating data. This means that your example is following these rules, and should not try to use a *post* form instead (although this is technically feasible, you would just need to replace your link tags with forms).

see [the HTTP specs](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html) on this matter.

Comment: Nitpick: The `$_GET` array will contain the *URL query parameters* of the current request. It does not really have much to do with the `GET` method or with forms. It's kind of a misnomer. `$_POST` also doesn't need a form, it just need URL-encoded data in the request body of a POST HTTP request, which is not dependent on forms.

Comment: @deceze thanks! changed the wording to hopefully clarify this.

Answer (score -1):

you may create a session based permission system that:

when user visited your site, and his/her browser rendered the link, in that php, you set a session variable for that link,

```
$_SESSION["permitted_recipe_id"] = $row['recipe_id'];
```

Now you know exacly what recipe id that user can click,

with this check:

```
$variable = $_GET['variable'];
if($variable != @$_SESSION["permitted_recipe_id"]){
   exit("error you do not access to this result");
}

 $query = $database->query("SELECT name, description, date_added from recipe where recipe_id = $variable");
```

This will ensure that user visited the page before it send a request. This solution will prevent consecutive POST requests to fetch all website data,

if you show multiple links that user can click, you must implement $_SESSION["permitted_recipe_id"] as an array containing all ids' that send to user as links.

but beware, multi tab experiences may create bugs for this solution. This is the idea, you have to carefully work it out for a relase enviroment solution.

Comment: This is against the *idempotent* nature of HTTP requests, against *REST* principles. You will break the user experience and usability if you implement such server-side state. Sharing links doesn't work anymore, for instance. Don't do that.

Comment: ok, now you mention shared links this solution completely rendered useless. Thanks for pointing that out, yet following a non autoincremantal UUID will do that.